# The StreamSource opening moment

Tags: java, xml, inputstream

I have a question about the moment of StreamSource initialization for Xalan transformation. This may drastically influence both synchronization and the project development itself.

The problem is, when exactly does the real input stream open? When the StreamSource is created from String path, not the File or other preopened Streams. Or, specifically, does the stream open at the moment of initialization, or at the first call (in transformer, for example, during "transform call").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The creation of StreamSource doesn't open the stream, it just set some attributes.

The stream opening is done when you call the method `transform()`.

Take a look at the class `com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl`

Comment: Thanks a lot! You saved me from fear and pain)